# SQL percentage of 1 column display in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a single column of Male and Female and calculated the percentages and displayed them as such,

```
Gender      %
M       50.8
F       49.2
```

How do I calculate the % such that the results is displayed on two separate columns?(Microsoft SQL) such as;

```
M      F
50.8   49.2
```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL, sorry I forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional aggregation using case when expression

```
select concat(max(case when gender='M' then valueofpercentage end),'%') as 'M',
concat(max(case when gender='F' then valueofpercentage end),'%') as 'F'
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, yet without having calculated the percentages, how do I calculate it such that it is displayed in the desired format

Comment: I would like them on two separate columns, as shown in the last line

Comment: @RoiboisTx, have you execute it - it will show you value in two columns

Comment: Yes, but I would like to include my calculation of the %'s in the solution, not just the values, it doesn't work if I simply plug it in there, how do I also include the calculation of the %'s in the solution?

Comment: @RoiboisTx, I've modified it - you can check now

Comment: I haven't been quite clear, apologies. How do I include, the calculation for the 'valueofpercentage' in the same query? not the calculated value of %'s, the query to calculate them, in the same query to display them in the desired format

Answer (score 0):

do aggregation

```
        select Gender,
        max(case when Gender='M' then value end),
        max(case when Gender='F' then value end) 
        from table group by Gender
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the display after the calculation, yet if I didn't have the calculated %'s, how do I calculate it such that it is displayed as desired?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Gender, %
      from tableName
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(%)
        FOR Gender IN (M,F)
    )AS pvt
```

if any issue then tell me.

Comment: Sorry, posed my question wrongly, I would like to know 'how to calculate' the % such that the display is on to columns

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when gender = 'M' then [%] end) as m,
       max(case when gender = 'F' then [%] end) as f
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer from fa06 is the correct logic, but you are having issues with calculating the percentage.

Here is something I just created to teach you how to work out percentages in sql:

```
declare 
@m as decimal,
@f as decimal,
@t as int

set @m = 50
set @f = 40
set @t = @m+@f

select Cast(@m / @t * 100 as decimal(5, 2)) as m, Cast(@f / @t * 100 as decimal(5 ,2)) as f
```

In this scenario, @m and @f are just dummy numbers and @t is the total number, hence why @m + @f, below is how you'd get the number of count in the table where gender is male - obviously change 'm' to 'f' to get females.

```
select count(gender) from tablename where gender = 'm' as 'm'
```

To do the calculation, you'd need to adapt it to something like:

```
Select Cast(Count(select gender from tablename where gender = 'm') / 
Count(select gender from tablename where gender in ('m', 'f')) * 100 as decimal(5,2) 
 as 'm' from tablename
```

Disclaimer - this code was not tested. But the logic is relevant if it doesn't work.

That's just for male and can be simplified far further by looking at fa06's solution, but just for purely working out the %, adapt the logic above - so:

> Number of specific gender / total number of records intended for the
>   percentage to calculate on * 100

Hope this helps